# How can I change the output of a "User.group(:age).count, for example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**EDIT**

This is what I have attempted:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Age </th>
        <th> Count </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tbody>
      <% @users.each do |user, n| %>
          <tr>
              <td> <%= user.age %> </td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The output in the view is just:

```
Age    Count
45
21
33
33
45
33
```

How can I put this into a table as described below, where it essentially combines equal values together and provides a count for how much of it is in the database?

**Question: How can I change the output of an active query record in my view?**

I'm trying to create a "statistics page" for my app, and everything is going swimmingly but I wanted to try and reformat the output of a piece of code.

Basically, users can type in their age, and this is recorded. The view displays how many users are of what age.

So, this is the code I have so far:

```
Users controller: 
@users_age = User.group(:age).count

Users view: 
Age: <%= @users_age %> #which produces (below line)
Age: {"21"=>1, "33"=>3, "45" => 2}
```

I want to try and change this output, to something like:

```
Age: [21 : 1, 33 : 3, 45 : 2]
```

Or

```
+-----+-------+
| Age | Count |
+-----+-------+
|  21 |     1 |
|  33 |     3 |
|  45 |     2 |
+-----+-------+
```

Is it possible to change this output? I wanted to do this because once there is enough data generated, it would become too much of a hassle changing the above format to what I need (essentially chuck it into an excel sheet and make graphs). Actually, is it possible to put this output into a HTML table, too?

Thank you

Comment: Hi mu, yes something like that. I'll update my view now, I forgot to add that line in.

Comment: @JamesWu i think you got your answer. right ?

Comment: Hi Vishal, thanks for the reply. The answer above showed what I should be doing, but I'm confused about how to actually implement it.

If I type it in as:

    `<% @users_age.each do |age, n| %>
    <% end %>`

It is nil value. I'm not too sure what I should be writing here.

Comment: By the way, it is not related to activerecord in any way. You get a hash from activerecord/database, their job is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this is what I attempted:
>
> ```
>   <% @users.each do |user, n| %>
>       <tr>
>           <td> <%= user.age %> </td>
>       </tr>
>   <% end %>
> ```

Your header contains two columns, but for rows you emit only one column. Emit the second one too (and actually use that hash you have computed in the controller)

```
  <% @users_age.each do |age, n| %>
      <tr>
          <td> <%= age %> </td>
          <td> <%= n %> </td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Sergio. I wouldn't have been able to figure out how to get that answer!